# Delphi divx player compatible with windows vista

Tags: delphi, dspack

I usualy use DSpack or DCAVIPlayer components to play divx avi videos in delphi 5.0.
Those two components are not compatible with windows vista. Both give run time error when you try to play the video. Any body know a vista compatible delphi 5.0 component?
Thanks

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: This sure sounds programming related to me. It's about compatibility of third party software components with particular operating systems.

Comment: At least post which errors you get. Maybe the problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I was also using DSPack and change to the [ActiveX of VLC Player](http://wiki.videolan.org/ActiveX/Delphi)

Comment: i also use ActiveX of VLC Player, plays anything VLC can, which seems to be everything ;)

Comment: Do I need to have VCL Player installed on all PC's I'm going to run my delphi application (.exe) on? or only installed on my PC where I'm compiling the delphi code?

Comment: @Ghada al-Naqi: You need to install on all computer you use your application